# How to design a highly available and fault tolerant file storage drop location in linux box

Tags: linux, load-balancing, ftp, fault-tolerance

Am trying to build a highly available and fault tolerant file drop location in linux server. Please find the current system design below:

[image]

We got 2 linux servers in secured zone into which several clients from unsecured zone will be dropping ***files*** in batch mode using ***xcom*** utility. Each client has got different times to send files based on business use-case. Now all clients have been configured to drop file into server1. But this design is not proper as it do not addresses following issues:

- If server1 goes down no way for clients to push files into secured zone unless configurations updated to send to server2 manually.
- If server1 goes down there is no backup of files in server2.

Am looking for a solution like a load balancer that can put files in a round robin fashion OR keep server2 in a passive mode(automatically accepts when server1 goes down).

[image]

Am not sure this is the best approach. Please share your views and ideas to achieve this.